# Capturing a Time Frame

Tags: mysql

Recently was posed this question and after trolling the internet for a while still find myself unclear. The end-user would like to look at some data output in 5 month, calendar blocks. 
Ex. 2012-01-01 > 2012-05-31 or 2012-11-01 > 2013-03-30. The relevant data table has an "interview_date" field (timestamp) with the first interview occurring on "2012-01-01 21:38:27". Is this something that can even be done in MySQL? If so, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to fetch all interviews within a certain period?

Comment: yes it can be done. write a query for the data between the date ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE (interview_date BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-31 23:59:00')
```